# getting a list of all the indices where two lists of integers of equal length have equal entries (in Python)

Tags: python, list

Suppose I've got two lists of integers of equal length and I want to create a list of integers which will give me all of the indices for which the corresponding entries of the two lists are equal. Is there a quick way of doing that in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it in a simple way with a comparison within a for-loop.

```
x = []  # preallocate array for index
list1 = [0, 1, 2, 3]  # sample data
list2 = [0, 0, 2, 3]
for k in range (0, len(list1)):
   if list1[k] == list2[k]:  # comparison
      x.append(k)
```

x gives you the index where the entries are equal.
So the result in this case would be

```
>>> x
[0, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.enumerate`. The sample data is provided in another answer by @QuangTex

```
list1 = [0, 1, 2, 3]  # sample data
list2 = [0, 0, 2, 3]
list3=[x for x,y in enumerate(list1) if list1[x]==list2[x]]
print(list3)
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 3]
```

Comment: The question is about the indices, not the values.